# Has any recent research been done on using fevers as a cure?

Tags: fever

I was just reading about fevers and the work of Julius Wagner-Jauregg, which was instrumental in establishing the usefulness of fevers in fighting off infections (as opposed to just an unpleasant symptom).

I'm curious if any more modern research has been done with deliberately causing fevers? I'm sure we could do so in a much more controlled fashion now (i.e. using drugs rather than malaria). And there are still plenty of diseases we have no cure for other than the body's natural immune system.

I imagine, for example, taking a drug to deliberately elevate a fever on the first day of a cold, in order to fight it off in a few days instead of weeks.

Has any more research been done on this?

Comment: What has your research shown so far?

Comment: https://www.thedailybeast.com/let-it-burn-why-you-should-let-fevers-run-their-course

Comment: And https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_Wagner-Jauregg